# Kubernetes Ingress with static IPv4 address

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, bare-metal

I have set Kubernetes up with kubeadm, bare-metal on Ubuntu Linux instances. These are instances on GCE, but I am not using the specific GKE native cluster service. Each instance (as a node) has a static, external IPv4 address. I am trying to make a service available to the outside using an ingress. I've tried MetalLB or port-forwarding, but can't get it to work. The former seems to require addresses to be commissioned on demand, which I don't have.

Is there a recommended way to get LoadBalancing to work with static, external IPs?

Comment: Could you provide your configuration manifests and more details about env? What OS did you use, Ubuntu/Debian? How did you configure Ingress, services. How did you test it. All steps to replicate your environment would be good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the offer to help. As I have moved on to a different approach it probably makes little sense to discuss all the details. I am now using Cloudflare's Argo tunnel to connect web content directly with the CDN.

Comment: Could you provide your solution as an answer? It might help others users who encounter similar issue.

Comment: Well, I don't have a solution to the original problem. I sidestepped the issue by tunneling between server pods and CDN. See here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/create-tunnel/kubernetes-sidecar-model

Answer (score 0):

I think root cause of this issue is the `Firewall configuration`. You can connect to cluster in a few ways. Below I will provide you examples of `NodePort` methods.

Assuming that there is a Kubernetes cluster is configured correctly (with `CNI`, [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl) bootstrap, taints, etc).

You can use below example to spawn `hello-app` pods that will respond to your traffic:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: application-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: application-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

#### Using `NodePort` service type.

You are using GCE instance so your VM already have static `ExternalIP`.

`Hello-app`  was deployed in previous step, now you will need to expose it with `service` of type `NodePort`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-one
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    key: application-1
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

By default, firewall will block the incoming requests on ports that are not whitelisted. You will need to create a rule that will allow traffic to enter on specific ports (ie. `31085`). For details, please check [Configuring Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall).

You can do it by following below path:
`Navigation Menu` > `VPC Network` > `Firewall` > `Create Firewall Rule`.

You can create a rule that allows:

- single port for `NodePort` for example `31085`
- whole range `30000-32767`

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        50m
service-one   NodePort    10.110.184.238   <none>        80:31085/TCP   5m53s
```

To reach your cluster you can use

***$ curl ExternalNodeIP:NodePort***

```
$ curl 35.246.148.237:31085
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-v5826
```

If you wouldn't create FirewallRule for this `NodePort`, curl output will be:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.246.148.237 port 31085: Connection refused
```

#### Using [Ngin Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) as baremetal considerations

When using `Nginx Ingress` you can use:

- Over a NodePort Service
- host network

You can depoy Nginx BareMetal using:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.2/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

It will create `Nginx service` as `NodePort` type. It's very similar to previous method, but difference is that your services can be `ClusterIP` and `NodePort` type.

You can apply Ingress to expose more than 1 service using this method.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"      
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /one
        backend:
          serviceName: service-one
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /two
        backend:
          serviceName: service-two
          servicePort: 80
```

```
$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         service-one                          ClusterIP   10.106.21.3      <none>        80/TCP                       2m4s
default         service-two                          ClusterIP   10.105.161.86    <none>        80/TCP                       2m2s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.110.149.194   <none>        80:31337/TCP,443:30417/TCP   6m31s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.98.15.73      <none>        443/TCP                      6m31s

### Output:
$ curl 35.246.148.237:31337/one
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-v5826
curl 35.246.148.237:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-8pfls
```